# Stored Procedure For Deletion in SQLyog

Tags: sqlyog

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `payroll`.`usp_DeleteDesignation`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `payroll`.`usp_DeleteDesignation`
(
IN DesgID int(11)
)
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
DELETE from info_designation 
(
Desg_ID,
Designation,
Desg_Description,
CreatedBy,
CreatedOn,
UpdatedBy,
UpdatedOn,
DeletedFlag
)
where
Desg_ID = DesgID;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error :
(0 row(s)affected)
(0 ms taken)

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
Desg_ID,
Designation,
Desg_Description,
CreatedBy,
CreatedOn,
UpdatedBy,' at line 12
(0 ms taken)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
BEGIN DELETE from info_designation 
( Desg_ID, Designation, Desg_Description, CreatedBy, 
CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, DeletedFlag ) 
where Desg_ID = DesgID;
```

it should be

```
BEGIN DELETE from info_designation where Desg_ID = DesgID;
```